# Is there a way to install a newer compiler to an older version IDE (VS 2012)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2012, compilation

I just started learning C++ very recently. The IDE that I am currently using is Visual Studio 2012 which I used to code in C previously, but the compiler that comes with it lacks support for C++11. Plus, the place I am in has limited internet access, so its kind of a pain to install a new IDE (VS 2015 Community is out btw). So is there a way to keep the old IDE and instead just update the compiler in it to use the new standards? I have a feeling that we can't do that, or else they can't sell their new products but I just wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler and IDE can, to some degree, be used separately, but I can't imagine that procuring and installing one and not the other is going to be anything other than a headache. If nothing else, you will likely spend more time and resources in doing so rather than just procuring the full suite in the first place. I suggest waiting until you are in a different place.

If it makes you feel any better, C++11 support in more recent versions isn't substantially improved anyway.

Comment: Or perhaps I can look for alternative compilers. Can I have a list of compilers + IDE packages that best supports c++11? By " best" i mean one that supports as many of the C++11 features as possible with minimal bugs.

Comment: @CodeBreaker: Clang or GCC, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can upgrade the compiler using the same IDE. IDE doesn't compile the code, and with time, has to upgrade the compiler standards.

For c++ latest compilers for your IDE, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154517/c-compiler-for-windows)

Hope it helps. 
PS- I'm using eclipse for programming in Java, c and c++. I have installed different compiler versions and use as required by the source code. IDE gives you the option to compile your code with of the installed versions of compiler.

Comment: Yeah, it would make sense for an IDE to have the ability to choose the compiler to compile your source code with. But the thing is I'm not quite sure how to do that in Visual Studio. Right now I'm looking at this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa.aspx) and hopefully find some answers.